# Extracting "lastname,firstname middle names" from a combined field

Tags: regex, macos, sed

This is a more complicate version of a question I see asked on here. I have a dataset where the forth field contacts a combined "lastname,firstname middlename(s)" and I need to use sed to break that into "lastname" "firstname" "middlenames"

Field are tab separated and the data looks like this:

```
01/31/2014  Teaching/Grad Ass   12345   Johnson,Robert S    09  etc
```

Output should look like this (tabs between the last, first, middle names):

```
01/31/2014  Teaching/Grad Ass   12345   Johnson Robert  S   09  etc
```

Lastname is between the fourth tab and the comma so pretty easy to grab. First and middle names are bundled together, sadly, and must be busted apart as a space, and some name fields contain no middle initials or spaces. Even then it's not that simple — some names may contain punctuation and some have leading intials. My goal is to output firstnames, middle names like this:

```
Name:
Adam,John
Beta,Sara X
Cruise,Jack A B
Derp,E John A
Egbert,Mary-Lu

Lname:  Fname:  Mname:
Adam    John
Beta    Sara    X
Cruise  Jack    A B
Derp    E John  A
Egbert  Mary-Lu
```

I used http://regexpal.com/ to build up a regex that worked great! But the same regex failed on my Mac, possible because Mac regex is a little different. And then it failed on my linux host (sed: -e expression #1, char 79: Invalid preceding regular expression). Here's the regex that worked in regexpal:

```
^([^\t]*\t){4}([^,]*)[,]{0,1}((.( )*([^[ \t]*]*))[ ]{0,1}([^\t]*)\t
```

UPDATE: Someone pointed me to the must better testing site regexr.com, and that helped me refine the regex considerably. I haven't tested it yet, but I see part of my problem is that a negated class match is still a match and that character is considered "found." So my bit about `([^,]*),` failed to find any commas because the commas were already found by the negated set before it.

```
(^(?:.*?\t){4})([^,]*),(.[ ]*(?:[^[ |\t]*]*))[ ]{0,1}([^\t]*)\t?
```

Here's the failed sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/^(?:[^\t]*\t){4}([^,]*)[,]{0,1}(.( )*([^[ \t]*]*))[ ]{0,1}([^\t]*)/foo/g' *
sed: -e expression #1, char 74: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

I'm trying to break it down piece-by-piece and try each in grep, but even that fails.

```
$ grep -or '^[^\t]*\t' *
```

Works ok, but

```
$ grep -or '^([^\t]*\t){4}' *
```

Finds nothing. This appears to be proper syntax and works at the tester site, but clearly I am clueless on some basic concept. Any advice or pointers would be appreciated.

UPDATE 2: I've discovered \t is not matching tabs in my regex, extended or otherwise. It matches "t" no matter what I do to it. Other special characters work fine; \w matches word character, \s matches spaces. \t matches t.

Comment: Use `grep -E` if you want ERE syntax to work. Otherwise you get BRE, which is what sed does *without* `-r`.

Comment: By the way, is use of sed really a requirement for the question? This would be much easier without regexes at all.

Comment: The end results needs to be a portable script I can run on MacOS, my linux host, or another platform with minor mods if any. These csv files come in every week and I'd like to automate the munging as much as possible.

Comment: Doh! I forgot the -E in the example. I think I tried it though and it didn't work.

Comment: If you want something that's guaranteed to behave consistently across platforms, use a language other than shell -- Python would be better. OS X uses BSD-derived tools, so you're always going to have incompatibilities between them and the GNU toolchain common on Linuxen.

Comment: ...*or* you can write for native bash, and not use external tools -- that minimizes your surface for portability bugs as well, and is the approach the answer I currently propose takes.

Comment: Since almost all of the work I do involves AMP tools I'd consider PHP (which I am passingly familiar with) but I would probably avoid other languages like Python. There's already too much to learn in a lifetime. =)

Comment: See also: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much simpler to write without using regular expressions at all.

```
#!/bin/bash
printf '%-20s %-20s %-20s\n' "First" "Middle" "Last"
while IFS=$'\t' read -r date position number name _; do
  read -r -a name_pieces <<<"$name" # split name into an array
  if (( ${#name_pieces[@]} == 2 )); then
    # no middle name
    printf '%-20s %-20s %-20s\n' "${name_pieces[0]}" "" "${name_pieces[1]}"
  else
    printf '%-20s %-20s %-20s\n' \
      "${name_pieces[0]}" \
      "${name_pieces[*]:1:${#name_pieces[@]}-2}" \
      "${name_pieces[${#name_pieces}]}"
  fi
done
```

Invoked like so (with literal tab characters rather than spaces where appropriate):

```
./split_names <<'EOF'
123     foo     123     Joe William Jay Barker  Foo
123     foo     123     Jim Barker      Bar
EOF
```

...the above yields the output:

```
First                Middle               Last
Joe                  William Jay          Barker
Jim                                       Barker
```

Comment: I can see a couple of ways this might fail.

* some last names include spaces: "La Morte"
* any names may include punctuation like ' - . 
* some first names need to retain the leading initial "R Scott"

Comment: @user3399043, sure -- decisions need to be made about how to perform splitting. Better that they're explicit ones inside code that's easy to read and edit rather than hidden deep inside a regex.

Comment: It doesn't *look* much simpler. Actually much more complicated IMHO

Comment: The point it being more portable is nice. The big problem for me is I have no idea what it is or how to modify and edit it. With regex I have a half a clue. Is this bash? "Decisions need to be made about how to perform splitting," yes... so where do I go to learn to use whatever language this is? It's at least worth a look.

Comment: Or rather: I already made the decision on how to split the data. Why I am here is because I don't know how to implement the split.

Comment: @Bohemian, how do you measure "complicated"? This is longer, to be sure, but each step performs a simple, clear action -- clear as long as you know bash. If you didn't know regexes, I imagine the regex version would look ugly too.

Comment: @Slam, yes, it's bash. irc.freenode.org #bash would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is `\t` delimited, then you can use `awk` to format. This might not be the complete answer, but should be enough to get you started.

```
$ cat file
01/31/2014  Teaching/Grad Ass   12345   Johnson,Robert S    09  etc
```

The following is not an answer, just a test to show that what `awk` understood as your fields.

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "$"i" is "$i}' file
$1 is 01/31/2014
$2 is Teaching/Grad Ass
$3 is 12345
$4 is Johnson,Robert S
$5 is 09
$6 is etc
```

So let's start to form our answer. We start of by stating that you want input and output field separator to be `\t`. The `BEGIN` block does that for you.

Using the above test, you know your name (complete) resides on 4th column. Since you have `,` and `space` between the first, last and middle name, we call `awk's split` function and pass those as identifiers for splitting. You can add more here based on your input data.

You then re-organize your 4th field in the order you want.

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
{ 
    split($4, name, /[ ,]/)
    $4 = name[1] FS name[2] FS name[3]
}1' file
01/31/2014  Teaching/Grad Ass   12345   Johnson Robert  S   09  etc
```

Since we can never tell how many middle name initial one would have, a little flexibility on iterating over them would be nice. Good thing about `split` function is it can tell us how many substitution it made. Using that to our advantage, we can do:

```
$ cat file
01/31/2014  Teaching/Grad Ass   12345   Johnson,Robert S    09  etc
01/31/2014  Teaching/Grad Ass   12345   Cruise,Jack A B 09  etc
01/31/2014  Teaching/Grad Ass   12345   Derp,E John A   09  etc
01/31/2014  Teaching/Grad Ass   12345   Egbert,Mary-Lu  09  etc
01/31/2014  Teaching/Grad Ass   12345   Adam,John   09  etc
```

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
{
    n = split($4,name,/[ ,]/)
    $4 = name[1] FS name[2]
    for(i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        $4 = (i==3) ? $4 FS name[i] : $4" "name[i]
    }
}1' file
01/31/2014  Teaching/Grad Ass   12345   Johnson Robert  S   09  etc
01/31/2014  Teaching/Grad Ass   12345   Cruise  Jack    A B 09  etc
01/31/2014  Teaching/Grad Ass   12345   Derp    E   John A  09  etc
01/31/2014  Teaching/Grad Ass   12345   Egbert  Mary-Lu 09  etc
01/31/2014  Teaching/Grad Ass   12345   Adam    John    09  etc
```

**Caveat:**
We hard coded `$4 = name[1] FS name[2]` since we know person would have his Lastname and Firstname in those two arrays and we then iterate through `n` number of middle initials. This currently breaks with the name  `Derp E John A` since we told `awk` that Lastname is `Derp` and Firstname is `E` and push the middle name `John` and `A`.

Comment: This looks useful, and the awk test was successful on my file. For some reason sed and grep are not recognizing \t as a tab and are matching to "t", but awk reported back just like your test example. Far too tired to parse the rest tonight, I'll be back at this in the AM.

Comment: @Slam Sure thing, let me know if you have any questions. Good luck! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Replace (,) with ([space])

Step 2 : Split the string in array using ([space])

Step 3 : Check whether the char in a[1] is 1, if yes then concatenate with a[2].

Step 4 : same way, Check whether the char in a[4]. if yes then concatenate.

I have managed to write the regex for First and Last name. Hope It will help

Regex to get the Last Name : `([^\s|^,]+)`

Regex to get the First Name : `\s\S(\s\w*\s+|\w*\s+)`

Comment: Step 1 wouldn't work. If you remove the comma you lose many last names in the jumble. "Van der Meer-Sacks,Mary Sue M." would become "Van der Meer-Sacks Mary Sue" and you'd have zero way to correctly re-extracting the last name — Step 2 would give lastname="Van". You have to grab the last name while the comma is still present, which is why I used "([^,]*)"